# find all n so that eventually all lamps will be turned off

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction, contest-math

> We have $n\ge 2$ lamps $L_1,\cdots, L_n$ in a row, each of them being either on or off. Every second we simultaneously modify the state of each lamp as follows:

- If the lamp $L_i$ and its neighbours (only one neighbour for $i=1$ or $i=n$, two neighbours for other $i$ are in the same state, $L_i$ is switched off;
- Otherwise, $L_i$ is switched on.

> Initially, all the lamps are off except the leftmost one.

> For example, if we take $n=4$ and let the binary sequence $b_1\cdots b_n$ represent the current configuration, where $b_i=1$ if lamp $L_i$ is on and $0$ otherwise, then we initially have the consecutive configurations $1000, 1100, 0110, 1111, 0000.$

> Find all $n\ge 2$ so that eventually all lamps will be turned off.

> Note that no odd value of n will work, as the proof below shows.

Indeed, one can prove by induction on the number of steps (after the first step, when the sequence consists of $2$ ones followed by $n-2$ zeroes) that the sequence always has a form consisting of blocks of ones of even length where consecutive blocks are separated by blocks of zeroes of even length ($\ge 2$). All entries between the second and second last entries of any block will become 0's in the next step. Then the first and last entries will be ones. So each block of zeroes will have its first and last entries replaced by 1's and hence remain even in length while each block of ones will have all but two entries replaced with zeroes. But the two entries that remain at one, assuming the block of ones is preceded and followed by blocks of zeroes, form two groups of two with the closest element in the neighbouring block of zeroes. In the special case when the block includes the first position, the first position becomes zero. If the block of ones includes the last position, the last position becomes zero. And so if the block of ones includes the first and last positions, it becomes zero in the next move. Otherwise, assume WLOG that a block of zeroes of even length follows the block and the block includes the first position. Then the block is replaced by a block of two ones, one following the block and one in the last position of the block. This shows that after one step the described form is maintained.

> So in particular, the above proof shows that there will always be a block of ones of even, positive length, assuming one never obtains a full block of ones of even length. Hence no odd value of n will allow all lamps to eventually be turned off.

> Also the next proof shows that any power of two will work:

For notational purposes, let for a digit $ x, x^{(i)}$ denote the digit $x$ repeated $i$ times in a sequence. We can prove by induction that for $n = 2^k,$ we can get a sequence ending in $1^{(2^k)}$ after $2^k - 1$ steps. For $n = 2^{k+1},$ by the inductive hypothesis, we can get the block $1^{(2^{k})}0^{(2^k)}$ because the last one after the mth step is at position m + 1 (and all other entries are zeroes, so they can effectively be ignored). This takes $2^k - 1$ steps by the inductive hypothesis. Then we can get $0^{(2^k-1)} 11 0^{(2^k-1)}$ after one step. Then one can prove that after $2^{i-1}$ steps, starting with a block of size $2^i$ in the center, we can get a block of size $2^{i+1}$ in the center. In the base case where $i = 1,$ we get $0^{(2^k-2)}11110^{(2^k-2)}$ after one more step. Assuming the claim holds for i, starting with a block of ones size $2^(i+1)$ in the center, after the first step, we get the sequence $110^{(2^(i+1) - 2)} 11$ in the center. Then after the mth step, we replace the first and last zeroes in the center with 1's and we replace the zeroes right before and after the sequence with ones, assuming there are still zeroes. So after each step we reduce the length of the zero block in the center by 2 (except for the first one, in which case the length of the zero block becomes $2^{i+1}-2$ for the first time). Hence after $2^i$ steps the zero block in the center becomes a one block of size $2^{i+1}$ and $2^{i+1}$ ones are added to the sides, forming a block of size $2^{i+2}$. Hence we take $2^k - 1 + 1 + 2 + ... + 2^{k-1} = 2^{k+1}-2$ steps to get to the all ones block of size $2^{k+1}$. One last step brings us to $2^(k+1)- 1$ steps in total and we get the all zeroes block.

> But what about other even values of $n$? Obviously once a configuration repeats, the sequence of configurations represented in binary will be periodic from that point on. $n=6$ is impossible: we have the sequence of configurations $100000, 110000, 011000, 111100, 000110, 001111, 011000, 111100,$ which is periodic with period 4.

> Note that the sequence is also symmetric; if one starts with the reverse of a sequence and the terms of the original sequence are $B_1,B_2,\cdots $, one gets the mirror image back at each step. That is if the new sequence is $A_1,A_2,\cdots $, then $A_i$ is the reverse of $B_i$ for all $i$. To prove this, we do it by induction on the number of steps, with the proof for the step being the following: consider a configuration represented in binary, say $B_i.$ Write $B_i = b_1\cdots b_n$. Note that for $2\leq i \leq n-1,$ lamp $L_i$ is switched on or off iff lamp $L_{n+1 - i}'$ is switched on/off, where $L_{k}'$ is the kth lamp represented by the configuration $A_i$. For instance, if $L_i$ is switched off, then $L_i$ had the same state as its neighbours $L_{i-1}$ and $L_{i+1}$. So $L_{n+1 - (i-1)}$ and $L_{n-(i+1)}$ have the same state as $L_{n+1 - i}$ by induction, and hence $L_{n+1 - i}$ is switched off. The other cases are similar. And the case where $i=1$ or $n$ is also similar.

> For $n=10,$ we get $1000000000, 1100000000, 0110000000, 1111000000, 0001100000, 0011110000, 0110011000, 1111111100, 0000000110$, and this is also impossible.

Comment: "$n=6$ seems impossible...." Don't you mean, $n=6$ *is* impossible? Have you tried any other values of $n$? $n=10,12,14,18,\dots$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've updated my question a bit. I've basically pointed out all the patterns I've found so far, though there might be a pattern for $n=10,12,\cdots$. E.g. all non powers of two might fail.

Comment: This is some old IMO shortlist problem... 2006 C1? Or maybe it was 2016

Comment: @The, it was 2006, but it only asked to show there are infinitely many $n$ such that all lamps are off, and infinitely many $n$ such that this never happens; it doesn't ask for all the values of $n$ for which they're all eventually off. https://www.imomath.com/imocomp/sl06_0627.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This CA is really fascinating in a few different ways. First, a more formal proof of a weaker proposition:

**Proposition**: No value $L = 2^m + 2^n$ (with $m \ne n$) will work.

WLOG, take $m>n$ and start with the first light on the left. By the arguments and notation of the second proof above, after $2^m$ steps, we will have the pattern $1^{(2^m)}0^{(2^n)}$, followed one step later by $0^{(2^m-1)}110^{(2^n-1)}$. But we would already have seen this configuration in reverse, at $2^n+1$ steps. By symmetry, this pattern must be cyclic.

Sadly, this isn't a proof for all $L = 2^kq$ with odd $q$, only those where $q = \frac12 (2^m+2^n)$. Tacking on an extra $2^j$ to the length doesn't give us a mirror image.

---

Second, something a bit less formal.

For simplicity, I'm starting from the right end, WLOG. This lets us treat the bitstrings as numbers.

First, note that no matter the length of our row, the only way to get the lamps all turned off is to first have them all *on*, that is, our bit string is all $1$s. But if you look at the patterns of the bits, you may note that sets of $2$ bits, $4$ bits, $8$ bits, etc., follow specific patterns. In fact, we can create the same CA in quaternary (using $0,1,2,3$ as four states) with a slightly larger ruleset. Looking at the lamp in question *and* its neighbors:

- All the same: go to state $0$
- All different: go to state $3$
- Left and right match, middle different: go to state $3$
- None of the above, and no $3$s: go to state $0$
- $003, 330$: go to state $1$
- $033, 330$: go to state $2$
- Last digit: the "missing" end lamp is state $0$, unless all lamps are in state $3$, then the end lamp is $3$.

Even more fascinating: we can do the same thing in hexadecimal, as the pattern that forms is so highly regimented. And, writing it as starting from the right, we can also look at the decimal equivalents, which factor interestingly. Here are the first few steps:

```
 N   Binary            Quaternary      Hex     Decimal + Factors

 1   0000000000000001    00000001     0001     1
 2   0000000000000011    00000003     0003     3      =        3
 3   0000000000000110    00000012     0006     6      =  2   x 3
 4   0000000000001111    00000033     000F     15     =        3 x 5
 5   0000000000011000    00000120     0018     24     =  2^3 x 3
 6   0000000000111100    00000330     003C     60     =  2^2 x 3 x 5
 7   0000000001100110    00001212     0066     102    =  2   x 3     x 17
 8   0000000011111111    00003333     00FF     255    =        3 x 5 x 17
 9   0000000110000000    00012000     0180     384    =  2^7 x 3
10   0000001111000000    00033000     03C0     960    =  2^6 x 3 x 5
11   0000011001100000    00121200     0660     1632   =  2^5 x 3     x 17
12   0000111111110000    00333300     0FF0     4080   =  2^4 x 3 x 5 x 17
13   0001100000011000    01200120     1818     6168   =  2^3 x 3          x 257
14   0011110000111100    03300330     3C3C     15420  =  2^2 x 3 x 5      x 257
15   0110011001100110    12121212     6666     26214  =  2   x 3     x 17 x 257
16   1111111111111111    33333333     FFFF     65535  =        3 x 5 x 17 x 257
```

We can see the left side of Sierpinski's triangle in the binary expression; all of the integers have only Fermat numbers as factors. The factorization pattern repeats, with every even $n$ divisible by $5$, even further $n \equiv 0,3 \pmod 4$ divisible by $17$, etc. One assumes at $n=25$, $65537$ would start to appear as a factor.

Now, informally:

It's clear that in quaternary, the only way to end up with all $0$s is to first get all $3$s. If there were an extra quat (quit? quoit? two bits) to the left, we would have the same issue as the original CA when dealing with an odd number of bits. Hence we can't have $L$ be any odd multiple of $2$. And in hexadecimal, the same argument implies we can't have any odd multiple of $4$. This *does* cover all $L \ne 2^k$, but likely has holes large enough for a truck.

Comment: You want $n\ne m$ I suppose?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Yes, I suppose so... I just left that as assumed as $m = n \implies L = 2^{m+1}$